# How to test a jsp based web application?

Tags: java, jsp, testing, web

What sort of a framework can be used to test a jsp web application?
All java classes and the servrlets needs to be tested too. What would be the best approach and related frameworks that can be used in this regard?

**Update**

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It is not relevant to my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the Java part I still recommend JUnit as Unit-Test-Framework.

For the test of the web part one can think about using a web test framework like Selenium. However, this part is more difficult to automate during (for example) a nightly build.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check the recommended frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your application front end with selinium webdriver automation testing.

you can test your java code with junit framework or
testNg now a days becoming more popular in the market

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check them.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit was selected as the testing framework for java components. Still looking for a method to test application front end?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called JspTester (http://jsptester.com) which integrates as a servlet to your webapp, and allows to inject values directly to beans, model objects, request parameters and session variables. Useful when there is a need to test the JSPs in isolation from business logic or MVC controllers.